# como validar que una cadena tenga corchete de apertura y de cierre en cierto orden

Tags: javascript, typescript

estoy tratando de validar si en una cadena existe palabras encerradas en corchetes

```
    let cuenta = 0;
    let data = "Hola [Mundo]"

      let posicion = data.indexOf("[");
      let posicion2 = data.indexOf("]");

      while ( posicion != -1 ) {

      cuenta++;
      posicion = data.indexOf("[",posicion+1);

     }

     while ( posicion2 != -1 ) {

      cuenta++;
      posicion2 = data.indexOf("]",posicion2+1);

     }

    console.log(cuenta)
```

si el numero da 2 indica que si tiene una palabra entre corchetes, el problema radica en que si cambio la cadena por

```
let data="hola ] como [ estas"
```

de esta forma tambien me da dos pero no encierra ninguna palabra alguna idea para validar eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizás mejor que uses expresiones regulares, como esta:

```js
let data = "Hola ][Mundo][, cuantos [corchetes] tenemos [aquí 1 2] o más"
const regex = /\[[\w\s\p{L}]*\]/ug;
const encontrados = data.match(regex);
console.log(encontrados.length)
console.log(encontrados)
```

donde, mediante el uso de [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) realizamos una búsqueda de la expresión regular que aparece en la constante `regex`, la cual detallo a continuación:

```
/\[[\w\s\p{L}]*\]/ug
```

- `\[` busca el caracter **`[`**

Luego se busca cualquier caracter único presente en la lista que aparece más abajo `[\w\s\p{L}]` donde:

- `\w` busca cualquier carácter de palabra
- `\s` busca espacios en blanco o caracteres invisibles
- `\p{L}` busca cualquier letra de cualquier idioma
- `\]` busca el caracter **`]`**
- `*` busca el anterior token entre 0 e infinitas veces, tantas veces como sea necesario

Todo eso lo encerramos entre los delimitadores `/` y en la parte final agregamos **u** para indicar que trate a los caracteres como UTF-16 (*unicode*) y **g** para indicar que sea una búsqueda global.

Answer (score 2):

creo que seria mas fácil si simplemente hicieras una comparación de la posición de cada corchete, de tal forma que posición 2 tiene que ser mayor que uno para que te lo acepte.

Te paso un código rápido de la idea

```
let data = "Hola [Mundo]"

let posicion = data.indexOf("[");
let posicion2 = data.indexOf("]");

if (posicion2 > posicion) {
    console.log('Tiene palablra entre corchetes')
} else {
    console.log('Los corchetes no encierra ninguna palabra')
}
```

Espero te haya ayudado la respuesta